# SQL Server version 612 , 655?

Tags: sql-server

I have SQL Server 2008 and VS2008 installed on my computer and I am trying to run a web application I've created on a computer which has SQL Server 2008 and VS2008 and VS2010 beta 2 with its SQL Server Express.

I am getting an error with the database version that is
"...aspnetdb.mdf" cannot be opened because it is version 655. This server supports version 612 and earlier...."

Configuring the database in Visual Studio ->Tools -> Options -> Design-Time Validation Database is not working since I don't have the SQL Server version comes with VS 2010.

EDITED : I also edited aspnetdb and inserted a few more tables so I need the same aspnetdb

Is there any solution to convert this db ?

Also, after fixing this, I am looking forward to upload it on my hosting which has SQL Server 2005 DB and configure it in PLESK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SQL Server databases have a version specific format. Each SQL Server runtime version (SQL 2008 SP1, SQL 2008 RTM, SQL 2005 SP2, SQL 2005 SP1, SQL 2005 RTM etc) knows how to upgrade to its own verison. Unfortunately, once upgraded the database cannot be downgraded. So if your MDF was upgraded to version 655, it cannot be downgraded to any prior version. If you know you're going to deploy on SQL Server 2005, you **must** develop on SQL Server 2005 too. Not only that, but the actual build number of your development has to match the build number of the deployment (or at least be lower than that): the SP level and CU level must match.

You can a attach the 2008 version MDF you created to a SQL Server 2008, script out the database content, then import the script into a SQL Server 2005 database of the proper version.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and when I changed `my_computer_name\SQLEXPRESS` with `.` to connect to server and it works and I could attach `MDF` file

Answer (score -2):

may be you have both services run.   (Mssql2008 and mssqlexpress) Maybe you have runing the mssqlespress running, that's the error that you have.    Try to stop the mssqlserver express service and run mssql2008 services, and attach again your databases.    I try this and works for me

Comment: I don't see how that answer even relates to what was asked.